# TypeError: answer() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Poll' and 'Answers' - django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I want to specify one of the table fields using serializers, but I get the following error

**Error :**

TypeError: answer() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Poll' and 'Answers'

**code : serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Answers, Poll ,Options
from authUser.models import User
​
​
​
​
class pollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ["pollAnswer" ]
​
    pollAnswer = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name="answer")
​
    def answer(self , Options :Options , Poll:Poll , Answers :Answers ):
        poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=Poll.pk)
        polltype = poll["pollType"]
        if polltype == 0 :
            return Poll.pollAnswer
        if polltype == 1:
            options = Options.objects.filter(pollId=Poll.pk)
            big = 0
            oid = 0
            for i in options:
                if big < Answers.objects.filter(pollId=Poll.pk ,optionId=i.pk).count():
                    big = Answers.objects.filter(pollId=Poll.pk ,optionId=i.pk).count()
                    oid = i.pk
            return oid
```

Comment: Also, don't call the object of type `Answers` `Answers` (same for `Poll` and `Options`). It overwrites the imported classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), a `SerializerMethodField` needs a method that takes a single argument: the instance of the model to serialize.

> The serializer method referred to by the method_name argument should accept a single argument (in addition to self), which is the object being serialized. It should return whatever you want to be included in the serialized representation of the object.

So:

```py
class pollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ["pollAnswer" ]
​
    pollAnswer = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name="answer")
​
    def answer(self, poll: Poll):
        ...
```

This method should return a value that can be serialized, I'm not sure you can return an object.

If you want the answer, you should return a string.